# Where to place user uploaded files?

Tags: java, file, file-upload, struts2, upload

I am creating a web-app that lets user upload audio, my question is that where should I place them? should I place them inside the `Web-Content`? or inside the `WEB-INF`? ( I do not consider to use database for these files since most audio files are huge) What is the best practice for uploading and storing files? as much as possible, as I deploy my application in a war file the files would be still there since I will store the relative file path of these files in the database

Comment: Do you care if end users can access the files directly without your permission?

Comment: never store user uploaded files in webapp, or deploy folder. You can put it in amazon s3 or rackspace cloud files something like that. Or have a configuration for file.repositry.path and store files there.

Comment: How do I create a file.repository.path? I want to easily deploy my app  , so if in case I move to another unit the files would be still there

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not a good idea to place the uploaded files under the web app at any level.
My preference is is to have a configuration file where the path is configured. It is important that the path is completely inaccessible from the web root so that no uploaded files can be executed on the server.

```
 create a text file called <webapp>.properties
```

Containing

```
 StorePath=C:/temp/Storage/
```

This text file should then be included under a path accessible from the ResourceLoader.getResource() e.g. classpath, WEB-INF

The property can then be loaded using java.

```
java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
java.net.URL urlx = ResourceLoader.getResource("<webapp>.properties");
props.load(urlx.openStream());
String buildVersion =props.get("StorePath").toString();
```

Then save the file to that location.

Comment: If you're building *and hosting* the app this will work. On larger projects, the hosting and maintenance will be separate concerns. In such cases I've found it easiest to keep the gist of this solution, but put the configuration in either the database, JNDI or system properties.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scenario you are facing, what will those audios be used for ? However it's always a bad idea to put the resources files in your webapp folder. You can store them in a separated folder that your app has permission to access or some remote storage which is mounted onto your machine or some other distributed file systems like HDFS or even cloud storage products like Amazon S3.

Comment: I am building a music site, and these audio files would be streamed. and I will store the audio files relative path in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to Upload your file in server storage place(Hard drive on in file system of server) create a folder in server and upload that file on it. After uploading put the uploaded path of file in database.

When ever user want to display the file fetch file path from database and show on your html/ jsp page and show path with appropriate html tags to handle it.

Like to display image you will save image on directory on server store its path in db suppose its path is `www.xrv.com/images/Sunset.jpg (`Absolute`or`relative`).

In jsp use `<img src="www.xrv.com/images/Sunset.jpg"/>`